# Animated external ad in SO homepage

Tags: bug, advertising, animation

I was under the impression that Stack Overflow does not allow animated advertisements, when seeing this ad on the homepage sidebar:

[image]

The ad has animation.

Was there a change of policy at some point? If not, can this ad please be removed?

Comment: Any more recent results than this [six years old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213770) (almost to the day) statement?

Comment: @usr25 - [yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306737/affiliate-ads-are-coming-to-the-network/306894#comment998903_306894); that's a comment from Tim Post in February saying that animated ads are still out.

Comment: Also this:  All ads must be static image files (no animation) with a max file size of 40k [(source)](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/engagement/solutions/ad-banners).

Comment: Well... Looks like it is forbidden, but simply not enforced.

Comment: Stack Overflow still has a no animation policy. We will address this animated ad tomorrow. Happy holidays....

Comment: @DammandCherry thanks! BTW, can you please edit your About Me and mention you work for Stack Overflow? (maybe only here on SO, I can understand why you prefer to not mention this in other sites.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Good point. Consider it done!

Answer (score 13):

I work with the Ad Ops team at Stack Overflow. Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

As @DammandCherry mentioned above, our policy has not changed. We have identified which campaign this ad is coming from and are working with the client to update the ad with a non-animated static image.

Comment: Is there no way to stop this programmatically?

Comment: This seems to be a CSS animation, is the ad policy clear on what the rules are for that? (I.e. the image files them self are static)

Comment: There also seems to be few other animated variations of this IBM ad

Comment: @codemirror adblocker, probably.

Comment: Looks like it is still in place. Policy that is not enforced is useless. Sorry, but thumbs down.

Comment: RedHat and IBM are doing it too. Info here: https://imgur.com/a/1RAL6pH (url was too long to post in a comment. Also included screencap of ad after the movement stopped. cute point: `nonanimated` is in the URL, but it sure as heck moved, which is darned distracting)

Answer (score 7):

Probably not an answer but

I just [saw this ad again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKrIy.png) and found the URL:

> https://secure-ds.serving-sys.com/BurstingRes/Site-113186/WSFolders/13680434//index.html

Moreover, this ad is not loaded as a static image, but an iframe:

> [image]

As @visibleman correctly guessed, this ad contains a static background image, with animation implemented in JavaScript and CSS.

Dear SO, why is it still there?

Comment: Because it makes them money, duh. Why people don't roll with an ad blocker for everything beggars belief.