# Are animated ads on SO questions accepted?

Tags: bug, advertising, animation

I thought from [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378301/1028230) that animated ads were not acceptable, but, at least on a question-specific page, I'm still seeing one from IBM and Red Hat -- the same one  I [mentioned in a comment on that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378249/animated-external-ad-in-so-homepage/378301#comment711244_378301).

I caught it this time too...

[image: please explain to ibm that this is animation]

Last time, it was headed to...

```
https://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click%253Fxai%253DAKAOjsu6YhjzZCcMeko2DaJF5s4sgibgEDwjofJHzLQBhTZSmsq2bvlFH-zWkQTR8iU5YExd0DmZBKr9SBrlixfAqIhGsPEBj0S9jU-Voif-Qq5asyZqGco5mOIKq_jGRFqUBANk1rhCT85DFwdZ4TzeEURUe_IT7s2upC_fKZQ_dyOCx-_0hBvfdRnANfs4qhL3YS00aQeDNjEkIujWnlqIZF3vPaqjEx6-LVvBPzdZ44RA3Z3PyJY6GXQJugJH6VekXdacVaklKlteKRD8JrN1eDcytA1DeQ%2526sig%253DCg0ArKJSzDHmhv_CEe4WEAE%2526urlfix%253D1%2526adurl%253Dhttps://www.ibm.com/thought-leadership/behindthecode/index.html?dev=ellie&cm_mmc=Display_N1114924.1948300STACKOVERFLOW-_-Corporate%20Advertising_Pillar%20Support-_-US_US-_-248584475_Ellie-Gen-V1-300x250-Nonanimated-Standard%20Load-Developer-NULL-NULL-NULL&cm_mmca1=000027HT&cm_mmca2=10006685&cm_mmca4=248584475&cm_mmca5=118167312&cm_mmca6=AMsySZYsEQ9L6qFjj_tJ0opGxaon
```

Again, I especially enjoy `300x250-Nonanimated-Standard%20Load-Developer` in the URL there. Nice. Just because it says nonanimated doesn't make it so.

It is distracting enough from the key goal of the site that I hope you can take it down.

More importantly, is there a better place to report this?

---

**UPDATE:** Still going on today, fwiw. 15 Jul 2019, 12:29pm Eastern. Question was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135658/fluent-validation-set-custom-message-on-custom-validation), link goes to...

```
https://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click%253Fxai%253DAKAOjsvGz_F2OixNreVX94rTOPSinJsKyN5rPEuphNpUDRzO3WUOybT_3K3Vf53vrGekaLv8wBhD1DThxW-ZDNg7amKfDSO_e4NEBjUF-9Z9awPlNodIzC15tAmUNjERDKLfJmTjTJiT4i78R1YwykNbVyUl3y2gY6DBc_OsyTkbFH6onw0vIt9QRVqrA6_puSZVNq14CN8DAf3vWpiaXzC4leyYMo0EcXNc8RwXCBX-gWjXfJ6v5QVGiQeVIFWAh1dPW4RdXgPS4E5Znh9oYnJrHSkqg68KZdCLihtDMw%2526sig%253DCg0ArKJSzK75Si83MGNIEAE%2526urlfix%253D1%2526adurl%253Dhttps://www.ibm.com/thought-leadership/behindthecode/index.html?dev=ellie&cm_mmc=Display_N1114924.1948300STACKOVERFLOW-_-Corporate%20Advertising_Pillar%20Support-_-US_US-_-248584475_Ellie-Gen-V1-300x250-Nonanimated-Standard%20Load-Developer-NULL-NULL-NULL&cm_mmca1=000027HT&cm_mmca2=10006685&cm_mmca4=248584475&cm_mmca5=118167312&cm_mmca6=AMsySZYsEQ9L6qFjj_tJ0opGxaon
```

Comment: [Who knows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329763/were-testing-advertisements-across-the-network/329818#comment1076849_329818)? Their position on it might have changed.

Comment: *groan... Not again.*

Comment: There are multiple (older) posts of SO saying animated ads are not acceptable (including [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/26/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/)); however, since their new "testing ads across the network" I believe [that's changed](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/were-testing-advertisements-on-the-workplace#comment19633_6157)

Comment: @Tas [Better link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329763/were-testing-advertisements-across-the-network) (also, it's "they're", not "their").

Comment: @JL2210 The possessive is correct here (*"their new whatever"*). Regarding the question, S.O. has an ongoing and growing habit of not listening to their users... Ok, the site is theirs, they can paint the whole thing in purple if they want, but some day (probably too late) they will notice that the users (a.k.a. we) are their biggest asset.

Comment: @Gera Where did I hear that ... ah - yes. Employees - they are the biggest assets to a company .... right before they get layed off to make some numbers look better.

Comment: [Pretty relevant here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386548/2370483)

Comment: @Machavity Was there ever an update on that beyond  2019-06-27?

Comment: @Lewis No. And I don't expect there to be. As I noted there, SO might find it unacceptable, but they won't find it unacceptable enough to stop doing it.

Comment: @Machavity Google might have told them to pound sand. iirc google requires all tracking, javascript and fingerprinting to be enabled for its partners, so there might not be anything more encouraging to share and there might not be a "give me only unanimated ads" option there either.

Comment: @JuanM You're linked in the above discussion. Is this one of the "animated ads are part of the experiment"? I have my doubts since `nonanimated` is in the URL. But if it is, how can I report that the experiment greatly distracts from the primary use _and value_ of the site?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Sorry. I said that while I was a bit tired.

Comment: Perhaps animations are needed for [a ten times higher revenue / valuation before the IPO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMfxd9y0cMY&t=15m57s) - from 70 million USD to 700 million USD (hence the change of CEO).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Great link. I hope the new CEO understands that I'm not going to spent as much time here if it becomes `<blink>MY AD HERE!!1!!!</blink>`land. If you lose many of your greatest assets -- here, those who _answer_ questions -- because the site is over- or even annoyingly-commercialized, well... That is, I don't know that `<blink>` is the way to INSANE PROFIT. And animations are pretty `<blink>`.

Answer (score 64):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. I work on the advertising team here at Stack Overflow. We have paused the animated placement on Stack Overflow for this campaign. We have also notified the advertiser that they need to update their creative to a static image before we resume this placement. Our policy has not changed, and we do not allow animated ads on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks Will. Can you comment on how this particular ad escaped the quality control measures? I think we've all accepted that, for whatever reason, the advertising technology used on Stack Exchange will always technically support animations (and, by extension, more concerning scripted things) - but wouldn't this still have been caught at the human review stage before the ad went live? The "whack-a-mole" approach (wait for us to see one _and_ report it) doesn't seem scalable. But mainly I ask because a combination of "the technology allows for it" and "humans don't vet it" is quite concerning.

Comment: Hello, Will. If you're an employee in the Stack Exchange company, would you mind filling in your profile so people can learn from it? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Yep, to follow-up on @LightnessRacesinOrbit, how can we catch this earlier? And **is there an easier way to report than opening a meta question?**

Comment: The ad is still going too. Just saw it again.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'd be happy to explain our process. We do a manual check of all creatives before campaign launch. Both when we receive the ad tag, and when we launch the campaign. What typically happens when one gets through, is that an agency updates their ad tags after we've launched the campaign. We periodically check creatives that are served by third party ad tags to try and catch this. Our advertisers understand our policy, and will quickly swap out the animation for a static image so they can resume the campaign.

Comment: Why do you allow unreviewed updates after launch? Advertisers have proven they can't just be trusted on this. You can check creative hashes at time of review and again when ads are being served. If there's a mismatch, don't serve and trigger for review of the updated version.

Comment: @WBT Do you have an viable alternative?  They know a manual review isn't scalable, but they minimize it the best they can, it seems like a heuristic that should work most of the time, and agencies probably update their ad tags all the time, so periodic checks should catch likely catch it at some point.  If they could solve this automatically they could have solved the first problem automatically as well.  Clearly it is such a hassle that it would be cheaper/more effective somehow to use manual oversight than automatic methods.  It seems they are being pretty reasonable in catching these ads.

Comment: Would a Content Security Policy with a fixed SHA on the ad work to at least detect when they replace the approved artwork?

Comment: Not that I disbelieve you Will, but you really should fill in your bio to reflect your role at SO or even get a mod star or something. Otherwise, random people who aren't staff can make the same claim to cause discord.

Comment: So, out of curiosity... Does this imply that Stack Overflow is OUTSIDE the scope of the recent "Advertisement campaign testing" that is currently being performed on the whole network? I'm asking because otherwise your answer would **contradict** [Juan comment here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329763/were-testing-advertisements-across-the-network/329818#comment1076849_329818) - "**Animated ads will continue to be a part of the experiment.**". As far as my understanding goes, the only way for both of you to be right is that Stack Overflow is outside the test scope. Is that right?

Comment: @opa There are automated ways to tell if something is animated or not. There are image formats that don't support animation, to which ads could be automatically restricted. If they're doing manual review of any new content, it's demonstrably possible and part of the system; changed content should be considered new content for this review's purposes. Based on responses [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329840/287315) I am not convinced they are doing a good job in catching inappropriate ads, *especially* if they're not even checking or providing easy ways to report ads (other than meta).

Comment: @WBT I've seen comments from admins on another site that runs in house adverting say that being able to update ads at will mid-campaign is a hard line that advertisers will walk away in large numbers if denied the ability to do so because running a continuous series of A/B tests to maximize clicks is a core part of their business models.

Comment: @DanNeely The same review process should apply.  If they have 10 different creatives they want to test in and out, then all 10 should be reviewed and approved, with the approved hashes stored.  If there is a required review step, *only* approved images should be allowed.  Advertisers should be allowed to substitute approved images for other approved images mid-campaign as much as they want, but why even require an approval process if it's not reviewing the less appropriate content that will actually be shown?

Comment: Have to agree with @WBT - as soon as a "malevolent" ads provider know that only the initial ads are reviewed it will predictably start with cute kitties photo just to pass the review step and then switch to actual damaging content afterward.

Comment: @WillWestendorf It seems that your answer is obsolete, the policy *has* changed, as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334144/) (h/t to [iBug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390027/))

Comment: **Downvoted since this post no longer reflects current policy.**

Answer (score 25):

#### Update October 2, 2019

> Good morning. **We do intend to display animated ads on Stack Exhange.** However, jarring and wiggling ads will be blocked and removed from our properties. Thank you for reporting.

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334144/350567) from another SE staff (emphasis mine)

Time to get ad blockers turned back on.

Comment: Ha, that comment is at -65 and counting. I've gotta tell you, that IBM ad was _much_ more annoying (**animation making the ad harder to ignore, making the SO content harder to absorb, making the site worth less to me, a decent contributor**) when it was animated than when it changed to static. Yep, adblock sounds like the way to go at this point. **Your audience is highly technical, SO (duh). They can handle adblock. At least on the SO site, you might wanna think about keeping the ads unobtrusive.**

Comment: @ruffin IMO *all* animated ads are jarring and wiggling. This is just another terrible move as the removal of Hot Meta Posts. SO is sucking now.