# Animated external ad appearing: 2019 edition

Tags: bug, advertising, animation

Just noticed an AWS/Verizon ad which was animated on the Stack Overflow homepage. I am assuming the ad policy hasn’t changed and this is just the 2019 version of this [similar 2018 issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378249/61654). I captured a couple of screenshots:

[image: aws verizon ad]
[image: aws verizon ad 2]

Comment: Relevant update on their position regarding animated ads: *"[We do intend to display animated ads on Stack Exchange.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334132/nsfw-video-and-annoying-animated-advertising-on-music-se/334144#334144)"*

Comment: You got in just barely under the wire for this "2019 edition".